# access vmware workstation from outside of host machine

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

i have a vmware workstation guest machine running on my windows 7 box. i'd like to be able to access the guest machine from other machines on the physical network. a single port is enough. is there a way to do this?

***edit**: the current config does have it as "bridged", and i can go out to the internet from the guest machine, but can't access the guest machine from any machine besides the host.*

Answer (score 2):

Just configure the VM's adapter type as "Bridged" and it'll get an IP address on the same network as the host (running VMware Workstation). Nothing tricky to it and very common.

Comment: as far as i can tell, that's exactly how i have it configured. the guest machine has a static ip. the host machine can ping it, the rest can't.

Comment: The guest has a static IP on what network though? Make sure it is the same as the hosts's NON-VM network (VMware installs several virtual adapters on the Workstation host). Or better yet, if the host is DHCP then go DHCP on the guest as well.

Comment: yup. host physical ip - 192.168.5.10. guest ip (statically assigned from within the hosted ubuntu) 192.168.5.26. more info - one of my boxes can ping the guest machine, but can't connect to any port.

Comment: Treat that guest machine just like any other box on your network when trouble-shooting. In other words, before getting too caught up in it being a vmware issue be sure to check the guest's firewall :-)

Answer (score -1):

In case you don't want to setup your vm network as bridge you can use a proxy to access it from an external device, check out this blog post for more information [how to access docker containers from external devices](http://blog.nunes.io/2015/05/02/how-to-access-docker-containers-from-external-devices.html)

Comment: -1 from me. Although the abstract networking concepts you mention might be somewhat similar in reality docker containers have little in common with setting up VMware  ...